# RxJava subscribeOn & observeOn & blocking w/ flatMap. Who does what?

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, reactive-programming

This is my first experiment with RxJava.

I am trying to use for a simple task: data needs to be exported from a database by a Java application. The export is done in three steps:

1. Issue a query to find the primary keys of the objects that need to be exported.
2. Batch those ids and, in-parallel, fetch/marshal the full objects.
3. Write the marshaled objects to the output stream.

I think a good approach is to have one thread doing step 1 (iterating over the pages of the ResultSet), a pool of threads doing step 2 (one task per ResultSet page), and the main thread doing step 3 (this needs to happen on a single thread).

I know that blocking the main thread is not seen as a good thing in the Rx world, but let's ignore that for this question. This is the first time I'm introducing reactive programming on a legacy app.

A test for the above scenario looks like this:

```
   @Test
   public void testSimplePipelineRx()
   {
      Scheduler idsScheduler = makeScheduler("idsExecutor");
      Scheduler dataScheduler = makeScheduler("dataExecutor");

      final List<MutablePair<Integer, List<Integer>>> stateHolder = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

      Observable<Integer> idsObservable = Observable.create(SyncOnSubscribe.createSingleState(
            () ->
            {
               print("ids observable initialized");
               stateHolder.add(emitIds());
               return stateHolder.get(0);
            },
            (state, observer) ->
            {
               if (state.getLeft() >= state.getRight().size())
               {
                  print("ids observable next - emitting onComplete");
                  observer.onCompleted();
               }
               else
               {
                  Integer val = state.getRight().get(state.getLeft());
                  state.setLeft(state.getLeft() + 1);

                  print("ids observable next - emitting " + val);
                  observer.onNext(val);
               }
            },
            (state) ->
            {
               print("ids observable finish");
               state.setLeft(-1);
               state.getRight().clear();
            }
      ));

      final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean> results = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

      print("Starting");

      idsObservable
            .buffer(2)
            .flatMap(i -> Observable.just(i)
                           .observeOn(dataScheduler)
                           .map(k ->
                                {
                                   print("Transforming values: " + k.get(0) + "-" + k.get(k.size() - 1));
                                   return "Values: " + k.get(0) + "-" + k.get(k.size() - 1);
                                })
                  , 5 //max count flatMap will have queued up
            )
            .subscribeOn(idsScheduler)
            .toBlocking()
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>()
            {
               @Override
               public void onStart()
               {
                  request(5);
               }

               @Override
               public void onCompleted()
               {
                  print("Observed done");
               }

               @Override
               public void onError(Throwable err)
               {
                  print(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(err));
                  print("Observed error");
               }

               @Override
               public void onNext(String str)
               {
                  print("Observed value " + str);
                  results.put(str, true);
                  request(1);
               }
            });

      print("Asserting");
      Assert.assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(-1), stateHolder.get(0).getLeft());
      Assert.assertEquals(0, stateHolder.get(0).getRight().size());
      Assert.assertEquals(7, results.keySet().size());
      print("Finishing");
   }

   private MutablePair<Integer, List<Integer>> emitIds()
   {
      return new MutablePair<>(0, IntStream.range(0, 13).mapToObj(i -> i).collect(Collectors.toList()));
   }

   private Scheduler makeScheduler(String name)
   {
      ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, new ThreadFactory()
      {
         private AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger(0);

         @Override
         public Thread newThread(Runnable r)
         {
            return new Thread(r, name + "-" + id.getAndIncrement());
         }
      });

      return Schedulers.from(executor);
   }

   private void print(String msg)
   {
      System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date()) + " - " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - " + msg);
   }
```

The output I get is this:

```
16:25:36.168 - main - Starting
16:25:36.185 - idsExecutor-0 - ids observable initialized
16:25:36.194 - idsExecutor-0 - ids observable next - emitting 0
16:25:36.194 - idsExecutor-0 - ids observable next - emitting 1
16:25:36.201 - idsExecutor-0 - ids observable next - emitting 2
16:25:36.202 - dataExecutor-0 - Transforming values: 0-1
16:25:36.202 - idsExecutor-0 - ids observable next - emitting 3
16:25:36.202 - idsExecutor-0 - ids observable next - emitting 4
16:25:36.202 - dataExecutor-1 - Transforming values: 2-3
16:25:36.202 - idsExecutor-0 - ids observable next - emitting 5
16:25:36.202 - idsExecutor-0 - ids observable next - emitting 6
16:25:36.202 - idsExecutor-0 - ids observable next - emitting 7
16:25:36.203 - idsExecutor-0 - ids observable next - emitting 8
16:25:36.203 - idsExecutor-0 - ids observable next - emitting 9
16:25:36.203 - dataExecutor-3 - Transforming values: 6-7
16:25:36.203 - dataExecutor-2 - Transforming values: 4-5
16:25:36.204 - dataExecutor-4 - Transforming values: 8-9
16:25:36.206 - main - Observed value Values: 0-1
****16:25:36.206 - dataExecutor-3 - ids observable next - emitting 10
****16:25:36.206 - dataExecutor-3 - ids observable next - emitting 11
16:25:36.206 - main - Observed value Values: 2-3
****16:25:36.206 - dataExecutor-3 - ids observable next - emitting 12
16:25:36.206 - dataExecutor-5 - Transforming values: 10-11
16:25:36.206 - main - Observed value Values: 4-5
****16:25:36.206 - dataExecutor-3 - ids observable next - emitting onComplete
16:25:36.207 - main - Observed value Values: 6-7
****16:25:36.207 - dataExecutor-3 - ids observable finish
16:25:36.207 - main - Observed value Values: 8-9
16:25:36.207 - dataExecutor-6 - Transforming values: 12-12
16:25:36.207 - main - Observed value Values: 10-11
16:25:36.208 - main - Observed value Values: 12-12
16:25:36.208 - main - Observed done
16:25:36.208 - main - Asserting
16:25:36.208 - main - Finishing
```

Why does the "dataExecutor" thread take over the "emitting" of values towards the end? I would have expected the "idsExecutor-0" thread to be the only one "emitting" values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the effect of the co-routine based backpressure design in RxJava and the `observeOn` operator: a request call coming from the emitting thread of `observeOn` may execute the generator inside `SyncOnSubscribe` (this is called weak-pipelining). To ensure that the `SyncOnSubscribe` generates items from a known thread, use `subscribeOn` directly after it (this is called strong pipelining):

```
Observable.range(1, 5)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.map(v -> Thread.currentThread() + "|" + v)
.observeOn(Schedulers.single())
.subscribe(w -> Thread.currentThread() + "||" + w);

Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is this documented? Everything I read said that the position of "subscribeOn" doesn't matter. Clearly it does!

Comment: It does not matter where in the pipeline you put the subscribeOn, but it matters on which observable you put it. You got two observables. The outer and the inner in the flatMap. The subscribeOn will create the observable on idsObservable. The Observable.just will be created on same thread and switch to dataScheduler by observeOn. The value will be pushed with switched thread down the pipe (toBlocking / subscribe). Therefore all your emissions are happening on a thread from observeOn after flatMap.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But not all emissions are happening from the dataScheduler. Some happen from the idsScheduler (the first 5, and then some more), and then others start happening from the dataScheduler. That's what made this confusing for me.

Comment: As explain in my previous comment, everything up to the flatMap will happen on subscribeOn. The flatMap will switch the emissions with observeOn to another thread. Everything down will happen on flatMap scheduled thread. This is exactly what the log shows. Rember that flatMap is a fork-join-mechanism. Therefore the source observable will emit while the flatMap could also emit. Therefore emissions from source and flatMap can be mixed in the logs.